# How do I get the list of n multiples of a and b without duplicates?

Tags: least-common-multiple

I'm trying to I get the list of `n` multiples of `a` and `b` without duplicates? something like this:

`M(x, n) + M(y, n) - M(LCM(x, y), n)`

where:

`M(x, n)` is the list of `n` multiplex of `x` and
`LCM()` [Least common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)

`M(LCM(x, y), n)` is supposed to remove all the duplicates which are the numbers in the list multiple of `a` and `b` at same time. For example:

```
A = M(3, 5) = {3, 6, 9, 12, 15}
B = M(5, 5) = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25}
L = LCM(3, 5) = (3 * 5) div gcd(3, 5)= 15 div 1 = 15
C = M(L, 5) = {15, 30, 45, 60, 75}
```

and then:

```
R = A + B = {3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25}
R = R - C = {3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 20, 25}
```

*I hope this is clear. If it isn't, tell me please so I can try clarify. I'm Sorry for such a math notation and tags. I don't know how to use it. I'm starting with maths and trying to solve a programming chanllange.*